# Geting EOF error when trying to use autopep8

Tags: python, autopep8

I'm trying to use autopep8 in order to correct automatically pep errors. I passed this command using the anaconda cmd:

```
$ autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive machin.py
```

I got this error:

```
for name in dir():
                 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

The issue is that I don't have this error when launching the script.
Is there a solution to this? Or is there another or better way to automatically correct pip errors using Python?

Comment: pls show the code block before and after autopep

Comment: Is that the last line in the file? You need to close that block.

Comment: the code hasn't been changed @luigigi.

Comment: please show it anyway. and not only that one line

Comment: I write just only the begining of the code here:  http://collabedit.com/q756w to see the code just tap HSN. @Seb